# Where can I find dragons for souls?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I screwed up with wasting 3 dragon souls on a shout that I didn’t really need for the Dragonborn DLC and most dragons I kill miraak takes the soul ;-; please help I can’t complete the quest without this shout since I’m on Xbox I can’t cheat the shout

Comment: Depending on how high level you are, this part of the DLC have caused me to restart my game at over level 30.  I always avoid his temple until I no longer need souls.

Answer (score 6):

Just finish Miraak's questline, and you will get your souls back. There are no places where you could farm dragonsouls, without the chance that Miraak will steal them. However, the shouts you need for the questline will be unlocked without needing dragon souls.

Answer (score 2):

Dragons will appear in [random encounters](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons_(Skyrim)) throughout the game. You can also look for them in pairs, but they are often in places where you can find other shouts. Other than that, they are in scripted story events.

Answer (score -1):

There is no concrete way to guarantee a dragon spawn immediately, however, you could just wait in a location that you know dragons sometimes spawn in, for instance, I sometimes run into dragons in Falkreath and the Mill near the Rift.